Я хочу сделать так, чтобы одна функция/метод вела себя точно так же, как и другая функция/метод
Что-то по типу такого:
Class1:method1(type1 arg1, type2 arg2, ...) = Class2:method2(type1 arg1, type2 arg2);

Или
Class1:method1() = Class2:method2();

Возможно ли это сделать в C++? Необязательно Class1 должен быть равен Class2.

А просто тип method1(type1 arg1, type2 arg2) {return method2(arg1, arg2);} (плюс можно std::move на аргументы добавить). В общем случае без повторного написания типов аргументов это невозможно, но если вас это устраивает, то ок.

Сделайте просто обертку, как рекомендуют в комментариях:
method1(type1 arg1, type2 arg2) {return method2(arg1, arg2);}

